# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected cu_dnnlstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2101, 17)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm

I am new to machine learning. I am having trouble getting my data into my network.

This is the error that I am receiving:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected cu_dnnlstm_22_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2101, 17)`

I have tried adding `model.add(Flatten())` before the dense layer. I would really appreciate your help!

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64

test_size_length = int(len(main_df)*TESTING_SIZE)
training_df = main_df[:test_size_length]
validation_df = main_df[test_size_length:]

train_x, train_y = training_df.drop('target',1).to_numpy(), training_df['target'].tolist()
validation_x, validation_y = validation_df.drop('target',1).to_numpy(), validation_df['target'].tolist()

#train_x.shape is  (2101, 17)

model = Sequential()
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

# Compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

filepath = "RNN_Final-{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.3f}"  # unique file name that will include the epoch and the validation acc for that epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("models/{}.model".format(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')) # saves only the best ones

# Train model
history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
    callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint],
)

# Score model
score = model.evaluate(validation_x, validation_y, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
# Save model
model.save("models/{}".format(NAME))
```

Comment: Is it alright that I am taking my train_x and train_y straight from dataframes like this:
```
train_x, train_y = training_df.drop('target',1).values, training_df['target'].values
train_x=train_x.astype('float32')
```

My data looks like this afterward:
```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.1344    ,
        -0.45      , -0.5844    ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.1293    ,
        -0.4209    , -0.5502    ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.1238    ,
        -0.3933    , -0.5171    ],
       ...,
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but EACH LINE in my array is a bunch of stock data that has been preprocessed. So, since the data shape is 2101x17, I have 2101 days of stock data. Please keep in mind, I'm brand new to this (and Python)

Answer (score 0):

The input to your LSTM layer (`CuDNNLSTM`) should have shape: `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`.

It looks like you are missing one of these dimensions.

Often we can oversee the last dimension in the case where the input dimension is 1. If this is the case with your model (if you are predicting from a sequence of single numbers), then you might consider expanding the dimensions before the `CuDNNLSTM` layer with something like this:

```py
model.add(Lambda(lambda t: tf.expand_dims(t, axis=-1)))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))
```

Without knowing the problem you are working on it's hard to know whether this is a valid way forward but certainly you should keep in mind the required shape of a LSTM layer and reshape/expand dims accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I am brand new to this and had copied the code for the adding layers to network from a similar project. I am passing in data that looks like this:

array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.139     ,
        -0.4806    , -0.6196    ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.1344    ,
        -0.45      , -0.5844    ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.1293    ,
        -0.4209    , -0.5502    ],
       ...,

Comment: Is it alright that I am taking my train_x and train_y straight from dataframes like this:
```
train_x, train_y = training_df.drop('target',1).values, training_df['target'].values
train_x=train_x.astype('float32')
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but EACH LINE in my array is a bunch of stock data that has been preprocessed. So, since the data shape is 2101x17, I have 2101 days of stock data. Please keep in mind, I'm brand new to this (and Python)